# Databricks not updating in SQL query

Tags: python, sql, databricks

I am trying to replace special characters from a table column using SQL a SQL query. However, I get the following error. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong or how I should approach this?

**SQL QUERY**

```
UPDATE wine SET description = REPLACE(description, '%', '')
```

**ERROR**

```
error in sql statement: analysisexception: update destination only supports delta sources.
```

Comment: Perhaps you're using delta lake https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-batch.html

Answer (score 2):

Databricks only supports updates for delta (delta lake) tables. The error message indicates that you try the update on a non-delta-table. So you would have to convert your data source to delta. For parquet it is very simple:

```
CONVERT TO DELTA parquet.`path/to/table` [NO STATISTICS]
[PARTITIONED BY (col_name1 col_type1, col_name2 col_type2, ...)]
```

See the [Documentation](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/convert-to-delta.html#convert-to-delta-delta) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

CONVERT TO DELTA parquet.`s3://path/to/table`
PARTITIONED BY (`column_name` INT) ;

--try this for partioned table

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).