# UPDATE destination only supports Delta sources

Tags: sql, databricks

I need to update the `Status` columns for the first 2 rows in `Original_Table`  where `Mobiles = 0` for which I am following the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19584388/13836950) solution and am getting an error.

**I am running the queries/updates on a Databricks Notebook** and using %sql magic command to run the query.

`Original_Table` is a Table I created on the Databricks Cluster

My sql code:

```
WITH New_Table as (SELECT * FROM Original_Table WHERE Mobiles = 0 ORDER BY Row_ID LIMIT 2)
UPDATE New_Table SET Status = 1
```

The error with above code is shown below:

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: UPDATE destination only supports Delta sources.
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56367279/databricks-not-updating-in-sql-query) question is possibly answering the same issue , but I am unsure about how to implement it in my piece of code , where my Aim is to UPDATE the first 2 rows where `Mobiles = 0`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `UPDATE` directly?

```
UPDATE Original_Table SET Status = 1 WHERE Mobiles = 0 ORDER BY Row_ID LIMIT 2
```

A reference [update-with-order-by-and-limit-not-working-in-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080403/update-with-order-by-and-limit-not-working-in-mysql)